# How to get all ip ranges from asn?

Tags: linux, networking, bgp

I want to get all IP address ranges/blocks from as number. I can search throw google but need to write them manually. I want to get them all at once? Is this possible to get only ip address ranges from websites at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whois servers instead of bgp.he.net or any other websites like this.

`whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS01' | grep 'route:'`

Just run this command on your Linux machine.

Comment: Is it possible to run in windows?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have whois installed, you can achieve similar using a direct TCP connection to the WHOIS server.

For IPv4:

```
echo '-i origin AS15169' | nc whois.radb.net 43  | grep '^route:'
```

For IPv6:

```
echo '-i origin AS15169' | nc whois.radb.net 43  | grep '^route6:'
```

Similar can be achieved with Python using the `socket` lib (in the standard library):

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(('whois.radb.net', 43))
    s.sendall(b"-i origin AS15169\n")
    result = ''
    while True:
        data = s.recv(16).decode('utf8')
        if not data:
            break
        result += data

result = [i for i in result.split('\n') if i.startswith('route')]
print (result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple one-liner using [IP Guide](https://ip.guide), which is updated every 8 hours:

```
curl -sL https://ip.guide/as16509 | jq .routes
```

Which will return something like:

```
{
  "v4": [
    "1.44.96.0/24",
    "2.57.12.0/24",
    ...
  ],
  "v6": [
    "2001:4f8:b::/48",
    "2001:4f8:11::/48",
  ]
}
```

(jq isn't necessary here, but it helps traverse the JSON-based response)

Answer (score -1):

```
sh ip bgp regex _<number>$
```

this shows the advertised netbocks from AS  known to the local machine (on a cisco, quagga or FRR router).  Some looking glasses will let you make this search (some won't).